# Gettin a “BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS” on ThinkPad Extreme Gen 2th

Tags: linux, thinkpad

I've installed PopOS on my X1 Extreme Gen 2 and it's been working fine so far except for one annoying thing which is that whenever I suspend the laptop (either manually or by closing the lid) it will go into suspend (lights on ThinkPad indicates sleep), and then when it wakes up (by manually pressing any key) it will present a black screen with the following text:

```
BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

I've noticed that sometimes the wifi doesn't work when I'm forced to reboot the OS.

Does anyone know what's going on, and how to fix it?

EDIT --------------------------------

The output of `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` is:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PEG0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.0
PEGP      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:01:00.0
PEG1      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG2      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
GLAN      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1f.6
XHC   S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
XDCI      S4    *disabled
HDAS      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1f.3
RP01      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:53:00.0
        *disabled  platform:rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0
        *disabled  platform:rtsx_pci_ms.0
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP04      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP05      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP06      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP07      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP08      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP09      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
RP10      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP11      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP12      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP13      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP14      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP15      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.6
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:52:00.0
RP16      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP17      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP18      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP19      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP20      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP21      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1b.4
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:04:00.0
RP22      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP23      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP24      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
CNVW      S4    *disabled
AWAC      S4    *disabled
SLPB      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00
LID   S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
```

---- EDIT

Output of `sudo dmesg | grep WRDS`:

```
[    4.803894] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[ 3323.493255] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[ 4427.419793] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

Comment: What does WGDS and WRDS stand for exactly?

Comment: I don't know, wish I did haha

Comment: Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147801/bios-contains-wgds-but-no-wrds) the warning does not seem important.

Comment: Is `XHCI` or `XHC` enabled?  Can you provide the output of `/proc/acpi/wakeup` in the body of your question?

Comment: Are you using an unsecured wifi network?

Comment: Since PopOS is based on Ubuntu, does [this Ask Ubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/1147801) help you out in any way?

Comment: @Ramhound I've updated my question.

Comment: @harrymc I'm not.

Comment: @AmandaFerrari - Disable `XHC` and see if the warning is generated.

Comment: @AmandaFerrari - Disable XHC (within `/proc/acpi/wakeup`) and see if the warning is generated.

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo dmesg | grep WRDS`. Are your BIOS and Linux kernel up to date?

Comment: @harrymc I've just edited my question to include the output. Yes, my BIOS is up to date. I'm also using dual boot, not sure if this changes anything.

Comment: The problem comes from the wifi driver. Check if a newer driver exists. Also check [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/538498/wifi-suddenly-stopped-working-on-ubuntu-18-04).

Comment: But are there drivers available for Linux? I though Linux didn't need drivers.

Answer (score 4):

This `iwlwifi` message is related to information stored in the BIOS about the WiFi device; It seems WGDS and WRDS are related to geolocation and radio transmission power limitations.

The message used to appear on boot or, in some cases, upon coming back from a sleep state, depending on the BIOS implementation.

- I say "used to appear" because the `iwlwifi` driver has been updated in Linux kernel version 5.6.8 in order to filter some incorrectly detected cases; If you update your kernel, or driver version, my guess is that message would disappear.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know what's going on, and how to fix it?

If you were to disable `XHC` wakeup trigger within `/proc/acpi/wakeup` that should prevent the warning from being generated.

> Per this thread on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987755/suspend-not-working-help-needed-to-debug), I disabled XHCI as a wakeup trigger in /proc/acpi/wakeup:
>
> ```
> $ grep enabled /proc/acpi/wakeup | cut -f 1
> LID
> SLPB
> XHCI
> $ sudo su
> # echo XHCI > /proc/acpi/wakeup
> ```
>
> and that fixed it for me. Oddly, this was only supposed to matter if
>   you had USB devices plugged into the machine, but I most certainly did
>   not.

Source: [Immediate wake-up after suspend](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393982/immediate-wake-up-after-suspend/438416#438416)

> If one of the output lines is XHC then that means that a USB device could be the issue. To test if this is the case, try suspend with the USB device disconnected. If you're machine doesn't automatically wake up from suspend, then it's probably a USB related.

Source: [Suspend not working - help needed to debug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987755/suspend-not-working-help-needed-to-debug)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work :(.

Comment: @AmandaFerrari - After you disabled the wakeup trigger you performed a reboot?

Comment: Oh, should I reboot it? I didn't know, I will try that.

Comment: It didn't work, unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

Some devices may have better drivers than those that come with the Linux distribution.

However,
[this laptop](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-x/X1-Extreme-Gen-2/p/22TP2TXX1E2)
is not new and the last
[NVIDIA driver for the GeForce GTX 1650](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/146629/en-us)
(is this truly your card?)
dates from 2014, so the driver you have might be as good or better.
On the other hand, it's also possible that the driver in PopOS just doesn't work well
with your card.

You could try to install the above NVIDIA driver, but take good care in case
this will cause video problems.

Comment: I already have installed the latest driver for my NVIDIA. I'm a little bit confused though, isn't the problem with the wi-fi card?

Comment: According to the description, the problem seems to be with the driver's handling of the wake-from-sleep event. I don't believe there is a hardware problem. You can test it by running another Live Linux distribution such as Arch Linux or Fedora and seeing if it behaves better.

Comment: Have you advanced with the problem?

Comment: not at all unfortunately :/

Comment: Does it happen when running another Live Linux distribution (non-Debian)?

Comment: Couldn't test honestly. I'm a bit out of time but will try this next week.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, you might try enabling the ninth PXSX entry down, which is listed in the output of `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` as `PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:52:00.0`.